# php to show array of $errors in javascript alert box

Tags: php

does anyone know how to return error array in a javascript alert box? The code below that I have doesn't do the trick right. Browser returns "Cannot use [] for reading". When using $error without the bracket, browser only returns the word "Array" in the alert box but the error message is not showing. Any help?

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error: '.$errors[].'");</script>';
```

Updated to include the extent of my code:

```
  $errors = [];
      $target_dirRFP = ('accounts/' . $order_list . '/rfp/');
      $file_nameRFP = $_FILES['FileToUploadRFP']['name'];
      $file_sizeRFP = $_FILES['FileToUploadRFP']['size'];
      $extentionRFP = pathinfo($file_nameRFP, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      $tempRFP = ($_FILES["FileToUploadRFP"]["tmp_name"]);
      $target_fileRFP = ($target_dirRFP . $file_nameRFP);
      $valid_formatsRFP = array("pdf");

      $target_dirPSA = ('accounts/' . $order_list . '/psa/');
      $file_namePSA = $_FILES['FileToUploadPSA']['name'];
      $file_sizePSA = $_FILES['FileToUploadPSA']['size'];
      $extentionPSA = pathinfo($file_namePSA, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      $tempPSA = ($_FILES["FileToUploadPSA"]["tmp_name"]);
      $target_filePSA = ($target_dirPSA . $file_namePSA);
      $valid_formatsPSA = array("pdf");

          if(!empty($file_nameRFP)) {
            if(in_array($extentionRFP, $valid_formatsRFP) === false) {
              $errors[] = "The RFP you selected to upload is not allowed. Only PDF file is permitted.";
            }
            if (file_exists($target_fileRFP)) {
              $errors[] = "Attached RFP: \"'.$file_nameRFP.'\" already exists.\nPlease select another file to upload.";
            }
          }

          if(!empty($file_namePSA)) {
            if(in_array($extentionPSA, $valid_formatsPSA) === false ) {
              $errors[]="The PSA you selected to upload is not allowed. Only PDF file is permitted.";
            }
            if (file_exists($target_filePSA)) {
              $errors[] = "Attached PSA: \"'.$file_namePSA.'\" already exists.\nPlease select another file to upload.";
            }
          }

          if(empty($errors)==true) {
            move_uploaded_file($tempRFP, $target_fileRFP);
            move_uploaded_file($tempPSA, $target_filePSA);
            $stmt = $DB_CON_C->prepare("INSERT INTO `".$order_list."`
                    SET first_name = '$first_name', last_name = '$last_name'");
            $stmt->execute();
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Submitted.");</script>';
          } else {
              echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error: ' . implode("; ", $errors) . '");</script>';
          }
```

Comment: Update your question with the value of `$errors`

Comment: you need to first define the variable at the top of your code as an empty array: `$errors = [];`

Comment: Okay, I'm new to the site. I just added. hopefully, it's more clear now.                                                .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `implode()` and entering new lines is most likely the best way.

Example:

```
<?php
$errors = [];

if( validateFails() ){
    $errors[] = "some error found";
}

if( failAgain() ){
    $errors[] = "some other error";
}

echo '<script>alert("'.implode("\\n", $errors).'");</script>';
```

**UPDATE:**

Another error lies on your error message string syntax. Take a look at this line:

```
$errors[] = "Attached PSA: \"'.$file_namePSA.'\" already exists.\nPlease select another file to upload.";
```

This should be re-written to:

```
$errors[] = "Attached PSA: $file_namePSA already exists.\\nPlease select another file to upload.";
```

As any variable inside double quotes `"..."` will be echoed out correctly. And a new line in the string should be `\\n` not `\n`.

Comment: Not working, CodeGodie. Even worst, the Browser didn't detect any error even though I purposely planted error for testing.

Comment: @ubuntujavy have you defined your `$errors` variable as an empty array?

Comment: I just did, but it didn't work. I just updated my question to include the rest of my code. I think there's a syntax error somewhere in there but couldn't spot it.

Comment: Theres a lot going on in your code. You have variables that I dont know what they are like : `$file_nameRFP`, `$extentionRFP`, `$valid_formatsRFP`, etc.. any of those can be giving you different results.

Comment: Can you check my code again? I just updated my code to include variables sources.

Comment: this site isnt the best place to do pairing debugging.. in fact, SO does not want you to post code for us to debug https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: I can do Teamviewer.

Answer (score 1):

You could transform your array in string with [implode()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp)

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error: ' . implode("; ", $errors) . '");</script>';
```

Comment: Doesn't work Rayann. Browser doesn't return any errors even though there is error planted for testing purpose.

Comment: My code is correct and tested, check my comment on your question.

Comment: I believe your code work, but for some reasons, it doesn't work on mine. I have updated my question to include the extent of the code. Can you check to spot what's wrong with it?

Comment: If no errors are being shown, the `$errors` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to create a single string representation of some sort.  For example, you could "implode" the array using a delimiter.  Something like:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error: ' . implode(', ', $errors) . '");</script>';
```

This would just be a simple comma+space delimiter between all of the array elements.  If you need something more complex or with more styling (in which case you *probably* don't want an `alert()` in the first place) then you could manually build any string you like from the contents of the array.  You just need to output a string to the page, not an array directly.

Comment: Doesn't work David. Browser doesn't return any errors even though there is error planted for testing purpose.

Comment: @ubuntujavy: Can you provide a minimal and complete example of the problem?  The code shown in the question doesn't guarantee that `$errors` isn't simply an empty array.

Comment: David, here is my error detection lines. if(!empty($file_nameRFP)) {
        if(in_array($extentionRFP, $valid_formatsRFP) === false) {
          $errors[] = "The RFP you selected to upload is not allowed. Only PDF file is permitted.";
        }
        if (file_exists($target_fileRFP)) {
          $errors[] = "Attached RFP: \"'.$file_nameRFP.'\" already exists.\nPlease select another file to upload.";
        }
      }

Comment: @ubuntujavy: Code belongs in the question, for obvious readability reasons.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to the site and didn't realize I could edit code after 5 mins. I have updated my question to include error detection code.

Comment: @ubuntujavy: And how have you confirmed that the array contains elements?  When you `echo count($errors)` what does it say?  When you examine the actual client-side code generated by this, what's there?  Include that information in the question as well.

Comment: Echoing count($errors) gives Array to string conversion error.

Comment: @ubuntujavy: Did you overwrite `$errors` with a non-array value in your code?  How are you trying to echo it?  Show the actual code and the specific error information, don't just give vague descriptions of things that sound like errors.

Comment: The extent of my code is included in the question. I don't believe I overwrite any errors. When I changed my code to your suggested change, the browser didn't even return any error knowing that there is error since I purposely put two files with similar name for the error to occur.

Comment: @ubuntujavy: If that's the extent of your code then you never echoed `count($errors)`, which means you never got the error that you claimed to get in a previous comment.  We can only help you with actual code and actual errors.  Also, have you examined the exact output in the HTML page source as suggested?  Instead of just relying on the `alert()`?  Also, your code does *not* explicitly add values to `$errors` for testing as you've implied. All of those lines are in `if` conditions. So perhaps those conditions are `false`? Stop assuming that the rest of your code *must* be working and test it.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you will get exact output.Please try

```
alert(JSON.stringify($errors));
```

Comment: Thanks. I got syntax error. Where would I be adding your code into mine? echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error: '.$errors[].'");</script>';

Comment: Yes  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(JSON.stringify('.$errors.'));</script>';

Comment: Not working Waquas. I got Array to string conversion error.

Comment: Let me check please